# Azure deploy pipeline with/without approval on separated enviroments

Tags: git, azure-devops, deployment, azure, azure-pipelines

I have two separate environments under my repository:

- development (Approvals are not configured but the environment exists)
- production (Approvals rules are configured via dev.azure.com UI)

The problem is, even we try to deploy to the development environment, the pipeline asking for approval. How we can fix the issue? Below, you can see simple two deploy jobs from YAML:

```
jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy_Dev
      displayName: 'Deploy Develop to Dev Machine'
      pool:
        name: Development
      condition: contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop')
      environment: 'development'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
              - checkout: none
              - task: Bash@3
                inputs:
                  targetType: 'inline'
                  script: |
                    echo $(hostname)
                  workingDirectory: '/var/www'
                  noProfile: false
                  noRc: false

    - deployment: Deploy_Master_to_Hotfix
      displayName: 'Deploy Master to Hotfix Machine'
      pool:
        name: Hotfix
      condition: contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')
      environment: 'production'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
              - checkout: none
              - task: Bash@3
                inputs:
                  targetType: 'inline'
                  script: |
                      echo $(hostname)         
                  workingDirectory: '/var/www'
                  noProfile: false
                  noRc: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Environment approvals work per-stage. Split your jobs into separate stages:

```yaml
stages:
  - stage: development
    condition: contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop')
    jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy_Dev
      displayName: 'Deploy Develop to Dev Machine'
      pool:
        name: Development
      environment: 'development'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
              - checkout: none
              - task: Bash@3
                inputs:
                  targetType: 'inline'
                  script: |
                    echo $(hostname)
                  workingDirectory: '/var/www'
                  noProfile: false
                  noRc: false

  - stage: production
    condition: contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')
    jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy_Master_to_Hotfix
      displayName: 'Deploy Master to Hotfix Machine'
      pool:
        name: Hotfix
      environment: 'production'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
              - checkout: none
              - task: Bash@3
                inputs:
                  targetType: 'inline'
                  script: |
                      echo $(hostname)         
                  workingDirectory: '/var/www'
                  noProfile: false
                  noRc: false
```